# How to automatically rotate a misoriented image in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

i have two Sample Image rotated 5 degree & 17 degree clockwise. how to code to tell the system to [1] firstly, calculate the degree of rotation automatically [2] secondly, rotate back the Sample Image to 0 degree automatically [3] thirdly, compare the automatically rotated Sample Image with Template Image

i have the following code but i got an error message ''invalid character in identifier'':

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("rotated 17 degree-Sample Image-defect.png",0)

def rotateImage(img, angle):
  img_center = tuple(np.array(img.shape)/2)
  rot = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(img_center,angle,1.0)
  result = cv2.warpAffine(img,rot,img.shape,flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  return result

img2 = cv2.imwrite("automatically rotated.png",result)

img3 = cv2.imread("Template Image.png")
img4 = cv2.imread("automatically rotated.png")

difference = cv2.subtract(img3, img4)

result = np.any(difference) 

if result is True:
    print ("The images are the same")
else:
    cv2.imshow("result.jpg", difference)
    print ("the images are different")﻿
```

I am new to opencv & python. Please consider including your correction into my code. thank you

Comment: If this is a how to question, it is far too broad. If you just want us to help with the error, add more details like the traceback.

Comment: please provide the image mentioned in the code as well